# Enable automatic driver install in Windows XP

Tags: windows, drivers

When Windows detects new hardware (be it graphic card or USB Peripheral) it automatically installs driver and if it can't find a driver it shows "Found New hardware wizard" that allows you to manually select a driver. My problem is that this "Found New hardware wizard" shows up every time when I plug a new device and I have to click Next Next Next.. until it finishes installation. It's just like in Windows 98 ;) I want to fix it to the way it's supposed to be.

It's got nothing to do with "Windows Update" and "Driver Signing" settings in "System properties -> Hardware" tab, those are on default settings.

[Here](http://www.techrepublic.com/forum/questions/101-244739/windows-xp-is-not-auto-recognize-drivers) is the same problem I have, but those replies ale completely useless

Comment: (1) Are you talking about hardware that have been plug-in before or plug-in 1st time? (2) Do you know if there is some system protection software installed?

Comment: The link you gave is for XP with SP2. Is SP3 installed?

Comment: So, you want to bypass “Found New Hardware Wizard” i.e let Windows  to Install Drivers Automatically, right?
Probably, this is what you are looking for [Click Here](http://superuser.com/questions/230838/bypassing-found-new-hardware-wizard-setting-windows-to-install-drivers-autom)

Comment: @inhabitant certainly a possible solution, but scripting macros to press next, next, next? Windows is backwards in some ways, but not that backwards. I'm certain some Win gurus know how to fix/automate this kind of thing. The real question is WHY is windows asking the user to reinstall HID devices on reboot - and how to make it act less like a demented alzheimer's patient.

Comment: Question is probably similar to this post:

[here][1]


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/160803/free-program-to-automatically-detect-hardware